# App crashes when I create a NSDictionary with integer as Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, integer, nsdictionary

Always when I try to set an integer as Object in a NSDictionary the program crashes without a message (nothing in the console). What is wrong in this code? :

```
NSString *string = @"foo";
int number = 1;

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        string, @"bla1", number, @"bla2",nil];
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `NSNumber` instead of raw `int`:

Modern Objective-C:

```
NSString *string = @"foo";
NSNumber *number = @1;

NSDictionary *params = @{@"bla1": string, @"bla2": number};
```

Old style:

```
NSString *string = @"foo";
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    string, @"bla1", number, @"bla2",nil];
```

Comment: You can only store Objective-C objects in most of the Cocoa collection classes, you can't store primitive types.

Answer (score 4):

In a dictionary you have to store objects, not primary types like int, char etc..